# I changed my app name, do I also have to change the bundle ID?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I changed the name of my app in Xcode. Now my bundle id is different than the one in Xcode. Because of that i cannot upload the app as a new build of what I had before. Should i change my bundle id back to simplify things or will that cause problems?

How should I proceed?

Comment: You can change only name and keep your bundle id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, change your bundle ID back to the original and you'll be fine. This is actually pretty common, you can see that the Snapchat bundle ID is for the original Picaboo app and Instagram bundle ID is Burbn.

You will probably need to change the app name in App Store Connect when you submit the new version too.